# How to access to my Factory service from jasmine in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Im not being able to make the service works in my spec

[here is an screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzG4P.png)

this is my spec:
**Books.spec.js**

```
describe('Books factory', function() {
  var Books, resource;
  // Before each test load our api.books module
  beforeEach(function(){angular.module('api.books')});
  // Before each test set our injected Books factory (_Books_) to our local Books variable
  beforeEach(inject(function(_Books_ , _$resource_) {
    Books = _Books_;
    resource = _$resource_ ;
  }));
  // A simple test to verify the Books factory exists
  it('should exist', function() {
    expect(Books).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

**Books.js**

```
   (function() {
  'use strict';
    angular.module('api.books',["app","ngResource"]).factory('Books',["$resource",function($resource){
      return $resource("http://localhost/codeigniterAPI/books/:id", {id:"@_id"}, {
        update: {method: "PUT", params:{id:"@_id"}}
    })
  }]) //end factory
})();
```

Comment: Please fix the layout of your message, and explain what is actually the problem.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to inject the factory into the spec file and also try to access to its method to validate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing. It'll be a good start to answer all of your questions.

To inject some elements you want to test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _YourService_){
    // Get one of your controller: 
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $scope = {};
    YourController = $controller('YourController', { $scope: $scope });
    // Get one of your service: 
    YourService = _YourService_;
  }));
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: i'll try it dude! thanks for your quick reply! greetings from Argentina!